# Chrome debugging and slowness in RN apps

Tags: react-native

Every now and then, my iOS simulator becomes extremely slow. Am unable to deterministically say when this happens. One solution seems to be "Reset Content and Settings.." effectively turning off chrome debugging and then restarting the app. Has anyone faced this issue ? If yes, are there any solutions to continue debugging in Chrome without any performance hit.

Didnt face this on the previous versions. Now on ^0.35

Answer (score 0):

React Native console.log will slow everything down if Chrome tab displaying the log messages is not visible. You can try react native debugger and see if you have same issues.

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger